# Are there alternatives to JNI for building Android apps with C code?

Tags: android, visual-c++, android-ndk

I am from a VC++ background.  Is JNI a must to build android Android apps with C++ code (on windows) ? Are there any alternatives, and Where can I find some sample apps and code. [Review of question is accepted :) thanks]

Comment: Using something like [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) should allow you to do whatever you need to do with C++, but without having to do JNI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample codes for JNI can be found under the installation of Android-NDK.
The link will be like `android-ndk-xxx/samples`. `xxx` is the version of NDK. 
I recommend starting from the example named `hello-jni`. It will help you in understanding the basics of Android-NDK and how it is linked with Android.

Comment: To emphasise this answer, the Android NDK (http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) is made available specifically to enable the development of Android applications in C++. It will require a bit of JNI, but you can keep it to a bare minimum if you want to. A good reason for that might be trying to get as much code as possible available cross-platform to iOS.

Comment: Thanks. I So, do we don't have alternate to jni, to use C language.